# How to do a task after scraping all the pages of website using Scrapy-Python

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to perform some task after my **scraper** **scrapes** all the anchors of a home page of a website. But the print statement is executed before processing the parse_details of all pages.

Any HELP would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
    
    def parse_site(self,response):
        next_links = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
       
        for next_link in next_links:
              yield response.follow(next_link,callback=self.parse_detail)
        print("Task after complettion of all pages")
       
     def parse_detail(self,response):
        
        print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@GETTING HERE################")
        all_content = response.xpath('//body').extract()
        print("###############")
        print(response.url)
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Your question is too vague to answer at the moment

Comment: FYI it’s __scraper__ not scrapper, and __scrapes__ (.e. __scrape__) not scraps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the method `closed` to your spider which will be called by scrapy after your spider is done. However, you can not yield any more items in the method. [Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed)

```
def closed(self, reason):
    # do something here.
    pass
```